# Driving +5V to a digital pin configured as output on the Atmega32

Tags: digital-logic, avr

I am a little confused about what happens if i **supply +5** volts to my digital output pin, Pinx, which is configured **output LOW**.
is it OK or will I damage Pinx?

Comment: Depends on the (micro-) controller. The Mega32 may get damaged - its outputs do not tolerate dead shorts, and the VCC and GND pins have a limited current capacity.

Comment: This is effectively shorting the 50 ~ 60 ohm RdsOn for the Nch FET to Vdd. and will get hot if sustained.  Mega32 which uses 74ALVC CMOS runs at 3.3V and has about half the RdsOn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ATmega32](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2503.pdf) maximum permitted DC current is 40mA per pin.

Here's a graph of sink current vs pin voltage. Note that it only goes up to 2V, at which point the pin is already sinking over 60mA. At 5V it could be 80mA or more.

40mA x 1V = 40mW. 80mA x 5V = 400mW, 10 times higher. If applied continuously it will probably destroy the output transistor, and could also damage other parts of the chip.

[image]

Comment: The chart above indicates that impedance of transistor in LOW state is 25-30 Ohms. When shorted to +5V rail, this would produce 150 - 200 mA of current, causing about 1 W in dissipated power. Unless the datasheet states that GPIOs are tolerant to shorts and are current-limited, this will smoke the IO pad, and likely the entire chip.

Comment: I agree that it will smoke the chip, but 25-30 Ohm impedance only applies at lower voltage. At 5V the FET will saturate and the current rise will taper off (you can see this starting to happen in the graph).